# Are pins supposed to have the same thickness by some standard?

Tags: pins, standard, jumper

I bought a DHT-22 temperature sensor, some other sensors, and some jumper cables. The cable and the pins on other sensors and a Raspberry Pi fitted well, but the pins on DHT-22 seem thinner. The jumper cables cannot stick to the pins, though they still work. I wonder if this is normal or the DHT-22 is a defective one.

That is, are the pin thicknesses supposed to be the same by some kind of standard?

[image] [image]

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no standard. Also, sometimes pins are round and sometimes they are square.

Comment: If you get crimp sockets intended for 2mm pitch cables rather than 2.54 mm learn to crimp them on wire and individually cover with heat shrink and they may work well for TEMPORARY experiments things that are a little too loose in the pictured sockets.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are many standards.

Wires, jumpers, sockets, and other parts made for use with solderless breadboards are made to fit together.  I don't know if there's an official standard for them, but the companies who make them make things that work together.

The DHT-22 is not made to whatever standard that breadboard parts are made to. The DHT-22 is made to be **soldered** to a PCB. Its pins don't need to follow the standards that solderless breadboards follow.

There's nothing wrong with your jumper wires and there's nothing wrong with the DHT-22.  They are just made to different standards and don't play well together.

Answer (score 8):

The DHT-22 has [0.5mm nominal leads](https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Sensors/Temperature/DHT22.pdf), which is similar to other through-hole parts. For example, the 1N4148 (JEDEC DO-35) has leads that are between 0.46 and 0.55mm (so about 0.5mm nominal).

[image]

The female receptacles on the jumpers are probably made to fit the [Molex KK 2.54mm](https://www.molex.com/pdm_docs/sd/022032021_sd.pdf) pitch standard (0.67mm square) header posts, so they will be loose and maybe unreliable on 0.5mm round leads.

[image]

Comment: If the two are two different standards, is there some kind of adapter (0.5mm female ==== 0.67mm female jumper cable, maybe) for this case?

Comment: It can be soldered into a PCB and a header also soldered into the PCB. https://www.robotshop.com/media/catalog/product/cache/image/900x900/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/d/h/dht22-temperature-humidity-sensor_2.jpg

Comment: So you could use a bit of perf board, or simply fan the leads out a bit and solder them to the short ends of a 2.54mm pitch header (less desirable mechanically).